# ConvertFrom-CSV from stdin

Tags: powershell

In Powershell in a script I'd like to **treat the whole stdin stream as a CSV file** and process something for each line. How do I do that?

As an example:

```
PS > type a.csv
"a","b","c"
1,2,3
4,5,6

PS > type a.csv | ./takeTheFirst.ps1
1
4
```

I tried the following:

```
ConvertFrom-CSV $input | ForEach-Object {
 $_.a
}
```

but there's no output. I am not sure about the "$input" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *almost* there.

Pipe `$input` to `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead:

```
$input | ConvertFrom-CSV  | ForEach-Object {
  $_.a
}
```

---

```
PS> type .\a.csv | .\takeTheFirst.ps1
1
4
```

Comment: Good Lord! So simple. Now when I think of it - it even makes sense.